# Solving inequalities involving floor function

Tags: inequalities

Why mathematica doesn’t  solve this simple inequality ?

`Reduce[Floor[x/2]<10,x,Integers]`

It returns the error:Reduce::nsmet

Is it related to floor function?How to fix it?

Comment: The following gives some hint how `Reduce` approaches the problem: `Reduce[Floor[x/2] < 10 && x > -200, x, Integers]`

Answer (score 4):

> How to fix it?

It looks like you need to tell it extra conditions

```
 Reduce[{Floor[x/2] < 10, x > 0}, x, Integers]
```

[image]

```
 Reduce[{Floor[x/2] < 10, x < 0}, x, Integers]
```

[image]

I do not know why `Reduce` did not generate these conditions automatically here.

Answer (score 2):

```
Clear["Global`*"];
```

It will handle the cases when you indicate whether `n` is odd or even.

For `n` odd,

```
Reduce[Floor[n/2] < 10 && Mod[n, 2] == 1, n, Integers]

(* C[1] ∈ Integers && C[1] <= 9 && n == 1 + 2 C[1] *)
```

For `n` even

```
Reduce[Floor[n/2] < 10 && Mod[n, 2] == 0, n, Integers]

(* C[1] ∈ Integers && C[1] <= 9 && n == 2 C[1] *)
```